# Shannon Entropy of an array in Typescript

Tags: typescript, machine-learning

I am trying to find the [Shannon entropy](http://www.bearcave.com/misl/misl_tech/wavelets/compression/shannon.html)  in typescript:

My code so far:

```
val =[0.5035203893575573, 0.4964796106424427]

shannonEntropy(val){
    let temp, temp2;

    temp = -(val[0] * Math.log(val[0]))
    temp2 = -(val[1] * Math.log(val[1]))
    return temp+temp2;


 }
```

It returns 0.693122394072697;
It should return 0.999964

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to iterate over the elements of the array and do some [math](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log2). What have you tried so far?

Comment: @jcalz I added more code

Comment: You need the [base 2 logarithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log2) of the number and not the [natural logarithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, your problem is that you need to use the [base 2 logarithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log2) of the number and not the [natural logarithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log).  JavaScript since ES2015 has a built-in function `Math.log2()` you can use:

```
const val =[0.5035203893575573, 0.4964796106424427]

const shannonEntropy = (val: number[]) => 
  val.map(v => -v * Math.log2(v)).reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0);

console.log(shannonEntropy(val)); // 0.9999642406577658
```

Or, if you need to stay ES5 compatible, you can use the natural log and multiply the result by [`Math.LOG2E`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/LOG2E):

```
const val =[0.5035203893575573, 0.4964796106424427]

const shannonEntropy = (val: number[]) => 
  val.map(v => -v * Math.log(v)).reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0)*Math.LOG2E;

console.log(shannonEntropy(val)); // 0.9999642406577659
```

Which, as you can see, is essentially the same thing (any difference is just due to numerical precision issues).

Hope that helps; good luck!